# Упростить код без использования условий и циклов

Tags: python, list, for, set

```
def is_valid_pin_codes(pin_codes):
    verification = set(pin_codes)
    if len(verification) == len(pin_codes):
        for i in verification:
            try:
                if len(i) != 4:
                    return False
                else:
                    if i.isdigit():
                        break
            except TypeError:
                return False
    else:
        return False
    return True

pin_codes = ['1101', '9034', '00112', '001a', '1101']
is_valid_pin_codes(pin_codes)
```

Передаём в функцию список из пин-кодов. Возвращаем True если пин-коды в виде строки, не больше и не меньше 4 элементов, не повторяются и хранят в себе только цифры. Если хотя бы 1 условие не выполняется - возвращаем False.
Хочу для себя знать альтернативные варианты, чтобы все работало быстрее, или, может, узнать новые методы для себя, которые мог бы использовать здесь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С точки зрения читаемость-количество строк такой вариант оптимальный:

```
def is_valid_pin_codes(pin_codes):
    if len(set(pin_codes)) != len(pin_codes):
        return False
    correct_pin_codes = [code for code in pin_codes 
                         if type(code) is str 
                         and len(code) == 4 
                         and code.isdigit()]
    return len(correct_pin_codes) == len(pin_codes)


pin_codes = ['1101', '9034', '00112', '001']
print(is_valid_pin_codes(pin_codes)) # False

pin_codes = ['1101', '9034', '0112', '0041']
print(is_valid_pin_codes(pin_codes)) # True
```

**Дополнительно**

Но при желании все можно записать и в одну строку:

```
def is_valid_pin_codes(pin_codes):
    return len(set(pin_codes)) == len(pin_codes) and len([code for code in pin_codes if type(code) is str and len(code) == 4 and code.isdigit()]) == len(pin_codes)
```

Также я рекомендую почитать вам про [list comprehenshions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), это пригодится в дальнейшем для решения подобных (и не только) задач.

Comment: Тут точно **True** во втором случае? Просто `if code is str` выдаст **False**. Надо бы `type(code) is str`

Comment: @DiMithras спасибо! это что-то из шарпа повеяло)

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать регулярные выражения для проверки. Возможно в данной задаче это и оверинжениринг, но если проверка будет чуть сложнее, то возможно регулярные выражения окажутся хорошим вариантом.

```
import re
def is_valid_pin_codes(pin_codes):
    r = re.compile("^[0-9]{4}$")
    filtered = list(filter(r.match, pin_codes))
    return len(pin_codes) == len(filtered)

pin_codes = ['1101', '9034', '00112', '001']
print(is_valid_pin_codes(pin_codes)) # False

pin_codes = ['1101', '9034', '0112', '0041']
print(is_valid_pin_codes(pin_codes)) # True
```

Здесь задаем регулярное выражение, что строка может состоять только из 4 цифр. А дальше с помощью функции filter проверяем каждый элемент входного массива. Если после фильтра осталось столько же элементов, сколько и до, то значит все элементы прошли проверку.

Comment: В вашем решении нет проверки на то, что в массиве содержатся только строки, а также проверки на повторы

Answer (score 1):

Можно очень сильно код сократить, если библиотекой [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) воспользоваться.
Да, это съест дополнительную память на подгрузку библиотеки, зато код получается очень компактный и чудесный.

> без использования условий и циклов

А ещё полностью убирает условия и циклы.

```python
import pandas as pd
def is_valid_pin_codes(pin_codes):
    s = pd.Series(pin_codes)
    return all([~any(s.duplicated()),
                all(s.str.isnumeric()),
                all(s.str.len()==4)])

pin_codes = ['1101', '9034', '00112', '0014', '1201']
print(is_valid_pin_codes(pin_codes)) # False

pin_codes = ['1101', '9034', '1456', '6587', '1201']
print(is_valid_pin_codes(pin_codes)) # True
```

Как работает:

- `s = pd.Series(pin_codes)`
  Приводим список к классу `Series`, который содержит полезные и необходимые нам методы
- В `return` одной строкой делаем валидацию:

  - `~any(s.duplicated())`

    - `s.duplicated()`
      Выводит массив из True / False, где значение True будет для повторяющегося элеманта. Первый элемент останется False. Т.е. для pin_codes из примера
      `[i for i in s.duplicated()]`
      выдаст
      `[False, False, False, False, True]`
    - оборачиваем в `any()`, получаем True, т.е. хотя бы один дубликат есть
    - `~` переворачивает значение
      Т.е. если есть хотя бы один дубликат возвращаем False — проверка не пройдена
  - `all(s.str.isnumeric())`
    Проверяем, что **все** значения не содержат букв.
  - `all(s.str.len() == 4)`
    По аналогии, проверяем, что длинна каждого элемента равна 4. Если хоть один выбивается, будет False.
- Собираем все проверки через `all`. Вместо all можно использовать and:
  `~any(s.duplicated()) and all(s.str.isnumeric()) and all(s.str.len() == 4)`
  Но для компактности по ширине, да и, в общем-то, читаемости, мне больше нравится вариант с all.

Comment: А чем это удобнее, чем list comprehenshion в моём ответе? На первый взгляд то же самое, только лишняя память из-за библиотеки

Comment: @Павел в list comprehension содержатся условие `if` и цикл `for`. OP попросил от этого избавится, поэтому такой вот вариант. Да и компактнее.

Comment: в pandas то под капотом явно тот же `for` и `if`, по компактности - да, соглашусь, получше

Comment: это можно сделать проще: `return s.is_unique and s.str.fullmatch(r'\d{4}').all()`